# Maximum data rate that can be achieved between PIC and FPGA

Tags: microcontroller, pic, fpga, clock, cdc

We are looking at PIC24FJ256GA705 here. It is connected to an FPGA and the FPGA must transfer a few kB of data as fast as possible. I assume that parallel transfer is the best option here, parallel transfer of 16-bits at a time. Some handshake signals must be worked out here since the PIC and FPGA operate in unrelated clock domains.

Lets assume a simple operation where the PIC reads the two 8-bit words and then stores it in RAM. The PIC is operating at 32MHz. How many clock cycles will this simple operation take? I think this is a 16-bit PIC which means that this reading should be possible in a single instruction actually. I want to then also consider the hand-shake signals and see what is the maximum data rate that can be achieved.

Comment: Note that you should be able to translate the clock domain inside the FPGA

Comment: Wide parallel  inputs into modern MCUs are an extremely rare design decision, fast serial interfaces or at least narrow parallel ones supported by DMA would be more typical.  This sounds a bit like an XY problem where you may need to refactor the task division between the MCU and FPGA.   But with what you've proposed, the speed is really something for you to research yourself.

Comment: Your PIC should be supporting SPI @> 12 MHz. Did you consider using that?

Comment: "As fast as possible" is meaningless.  There's got to be some maximum transfer time above which your system is just broken and there's no point, and some minimum below which no advantage is gained.  So -- what's that range, and how many bits exactly?

Comment: @Mitu Raj, yes we could use SPI. However, there is this requirement that the data should be transferred as fast as possible and then the FPGA put into a power down state.

Comment: @TimWescott, the "As fast as possible" is certainly meaningless. However, the point is how the PIC can keep up with fast streaming data from the FPGA or if at all. It is not simple to answer this question. We are trying to decide if the FPGA should be in charge of the transfers or the PIC. If the PIC is in charge, it reads samples of data if/when it is able to do so. The data from an ADC interfaced with the FPGA.

Comment: Please make your comment to Mitu Raj part of your question -- it sounds like "as fast as possible" really means "with the least on-time between measurement and transfer complete".

Comment: I'd look into the SPI solution.  Using DMA can make things pretty fast, and -- assuming that your FPGA clock is faster than the clock in the PIC24 -- having the PIC be the SPI master will probably let you run it at least 2x faster.  Read that nice datasheet!

Comment: After looking at the datasheet for DMA, I do arrive at the same conclusion. Its just that I am a VHDL FPGA person and not expert with microcontrollers. Anyway, is there some issue in use of parallel transfer from FPGA to the PIC (data word is 12 bits) and the PIC DMA then copies it into internal RAM or somewhere else? Things are more clear with SPI but am not sure how the handshake would work if parallel transfer with DMA is used.

Comment: In terms of power, you can suspend most of the FPGA and leave just a simple state machine to transfer data out of the block RAM.  Remember, the power consumption of modern logic is heavily dominated by dynamic change, if it's not going kerchunk every clock it's not drawing much.  Typically an MCU is faster as the timing master since the software can dictate rather than respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIC24FJ256GA705 data sheet lists a couple of FIFO modes in addition to SPI and I2S. Maybe that is what you’re looking  for.

Deal with the clock domain conversion in the FPGA.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at using the PIC24F DMA controller to transfer SPI data directly into RAM.

You'll have to read the datasheet to figure out what data rates are possible.